# Rust lifetime with a vec! does not work as intended

Tags: reference, scope, rust, lifetime

I love rust and I want to master it, but I am having difficulties.

Surely its about lifetimes. I still have a hard time getting my head around it yet. I show you some code here. There you can see a struct which holds a borrowed array.

When creating the CTOR for that Canvas I fail in declaring the lifetime `'a` the right way.

```
struct Canvas<'a>{ 
  width: i32,
  height: i32, 
  array: &'a Vec<char>
}

impl <'a>Canvas<'a>{
  fn new(width: i32, height: i32) -> Canvas<'a>{
    Canvas {
      width: width,
      height: height,
      array: &vec!['x'; (width*height) as usize]
  }
}
```

Error says:

> Reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 9:49

I understand the problem here - but can't find any example how to do it right. I nearly put `'a` on every position possible :D

### Edit

It was mentioned that I should not put the array as reference into my struct - how should it look to be right?

Comment: oh? ok - I'll take a look and remove if question git answered there!

Comment: You probably should put the vector into the struct, not only a reference.

Comment: can you syntactically show me what you mean?

Comment: @xetra11 `struct Canvas { width: i32, height: i32, array: Vec<char> }`, something like this.